# Rails Controller Display a of List of Resources/Objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

For my app I have three models: `Quotes`, `Images`, `Videos`, all of them I consider `content`. I want to call the `index` action of my `ContententController` to display a mix of these objects in JSON format. For example, I get something like this back.

```
[
{ ...image json... },
{ ...image json... },
{  ...video json... }, 
{ ...quote json... },
{ ...image json... }
]
```

How would I approach this? I feel like this has something to do with an SQL UNION? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider all three "content", then you really should use a single table inheritance strategy where they all inherit from the Content model. That way you can call

```
@Contents = Content.all.whatever
```

Instead of having to call each and then mix them together, or getting more complex then you need with the query. Turning them into JSON would then be easy considering each object would have its normal to_json method called on it, when doing something like this

```
format.json {render :json => @Contents}
```

Comment: I was thinking about inheritance, but I wasn't sure how the specific implementation will work out. Will they share the same table? So instead of 3 tables I will only have one, the content table? But then there will be a HUGE list of columns in that table, for example there will be a `url` column for videos that doesn't apply to quote or images, and the list goes on. In my mind one model = one table and the relationship between models = one table, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how inheritance this will work in this situation.

Comment: Yes there will be some column that do not apply, but thats fine, unless your talking about each object having 100 of unique columns, but then again if thats the case then you most likely need to move some of those columns on to an associated object anyway. Its like the old example of Cat and Dog objects inheriting from Mammal, clearly both cat and dog do have attributes that they don't share, but that doesn't mean that they should not inherit from it. Same logic here.

Comment: Yeah I believe your solution is the best and I've implemented it, it just feels a bit unnatural for me since they all share the same table. Thank you so much for teaching me about single table inheritance!!!

Answer (score 0):

`def index
    @quotes = Quotes.all
    @images = Image.all
    @videos = Video.all
    @contents = @quotes + @images + @videos
    format.json {render :json => @contents}
end`

I think you can just append each object, but I wont recommend you to do that.

Comment: It works if you add the .to_json method to each of those variables. But I'm wondering if single table inheritance is a cleaner solution.